# How to include a module in a model when Rails application is started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to do that? I tried this way inside my `Engine`:

```
config.to_prepare do
  ActiveSupport.on_load :active_model do
    include AAnyModule
  end
end
```

But didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean, "loaded or called"?

Comment: For example, assuming I have the model "A", and I run ```rails c``` in the console, after that I run "A", the code ```include AAnyModule``` must be runned. Understood?

Answer (score 1):

For including a module in a model, you can just add the include statement in the model itself. That will automatically load the module when you start the rails console.

Try this:

```
 class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   include AAnyModule
 end
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I want. I want to included in each models, without typing "include ..." on all model. Understood?